# Install Kivy dependencies on Google colab

Tags: python, kivy, google-colaboratory

My computer doesn't have a good graphics card. So tried installing Kivy on Colab and it installed successfully, but trying to install the dependencies gives me an error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   kivy.deps.sdl2 (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution
>   found for kivy.deps.sdl2

Answer (score 1):

## Colab OS - Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic

Colab runs on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic. Run the following on a new cell.

```
!lsb_release -a
```

## Install Kivy Dependencies - SDL2

```
!sudo apt-get install -y \
    python3-pip \
    build-essential \
    git \
    python3 \
    python3-dev \
    ffmpeg \
    libsdl2-dev \
    libsdl2-image-dev \
    libsdl2-mixer-dev \
    libsdl2-ttf-dev \
    libportmidi-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    zlib1g-dev
```

## Install GStreamer

```
!sudo apt-get install -y \
    libgstreamer1.0 \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-base \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
```